# iOS App Archive validation failed due to erros

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I try to archive an app upload to App store, but i face some problems. When I `Validate` my apps. It shows two errors:

- `iTunes Store operation failed.`

Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later.

- `iTunes Store operation failed.`

Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.
```

---

To problem 1:

I use three photos:`640 × 1136(1x)`; `750 × 1134(2x)`;`1242 × 2208(3x)`

To problem 2:

- My System and Xcode is: `macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195)`, `Version 8.3 (8E162)`. I think both of them are not beta version. So, the error make me confused.
- But I tried to change my `info.list` according to some other solutions:
  [the info list like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMCBc.jpg)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'd suggest first just waiting 24 hours. Sometimes there's a problem at Apple's end and it just clears up.

Comment: Regards to the first issue - are the images part of the Assets in your app? That what I use. Regards to the second issue - update Xcode, if possible *through* the app store. My version is 8.3.3 build 8E3004b, which is newer. (You have nothing to lose, right?)

Comment: Some time apple's problem makes frustrate !

Comment: hello, the first issue have been fixed after I delete 1x, 2x images

Comment: What is your minimum compatible version for your app with Xcode and iOS? General -> Deployment Info -> Deployment Target and on the right bar Project Document->Project Format

For your second issue, I did have a Beta version. I changed my versions by looking at the current active on Wikipedia. Build the archive, then open the archive and change its info.plist (you can right click on an archive and say show in finder, check if the values are right). That being said, a new update came out recently. If you just updated... wait a day as Matt said.

Comment: Hello, Diesel... the Deployment Target is 10.3, and Project Format is Xcode 3.2 - compatible

Answer (score 3):

Follow @Diesel advice, I change my info.list with the latest version of Xcode and maxOS, I successfully validate.

I change two area in my `info.list.`

- `BuildMachineOSBuild`:`16G29`
- `DTXcodeBuild`:`8E2004b`

---

Open your `info.list`

1. `Right Click` your archive > `Show in Finder`
2. `Right click` your archive > `Show package contents`
3. Products > Applications > xxxx.app
4. `Right click` your xxxx.app > `Show package contents`
5. Double click `info.list`
6. Replace `BuildMachineOSBuild`:`16G29` and `DTXcodeBuild`:`8E2004b`.

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've seen it several times where a day after an update you get these errors until they update their side. All that being said, glad you got it going!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!